# Scanning environment from different private network

Tags: vpn

My problem is pretty tricky to explain. I have a server on which Nessus is installed. And I am connecting to it via ssh. The server I need to scan is on a different private network. I have access to it via a VPN client on my local computer. The problem is that I don't have this VPN client on my server. Is there a possibility to make some kind of tunnel or forwarding to connect? Maybe somehow export config from the client on Windows and based on that create .ovpn config file?

Here is a very basic picture for a better understanding

[image]

Comment: This really isn't a security question, but a pure networking question, despite you trying to tunnel a vulnerability scanner. You want to know how to tunnel traffic from your local network over your client VPN connection.

Comment: You need to setup "my PC" as a Gateway for the VPN-IP-segment (usually as a static route, never worked with nessus before)